# Heating a black body

Tags: thermodynamics, thermal-radiation, blackbody

By definition, Black body has absotivity=emmisstivity=1. This means the black body radiates all energy it accepts.

Does this mean the black body cant be heated?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Every body **in thermal equilibrium** radiates the same amount of energy that it receives, otherwise its temperature would change until it attained equilibrium. This is not unique to black bodies.

Suppose an object, not necessarily a black body, is at a temperature $T_1$ and its surroundings are at a temperature $T_2$, then the rate of radiation by the object is:

$$ j_1 = \epsilon \sigma T_1^4 $$

and the rate its surrounds heat it is:

$$ j_2 = \epsilon \sigma T_2^4 $$

So the net heat flow is:

$$ j = j_2 - j_1 = \epsilon \sigma(T_2^4 - T_1^4) $$

If the internal and external temperatures aren't equal there will be a net heat flow and the object will heat or cool. The only special thing about a black body is that the emmissivity, $\epsilon$, is equal to one so the black body reaches equilibrium faster than any other type of body.

Answer (score 0):

In the real world, yes, you can heat a Black Body since there needs to be a temperature difference for a Black Body to release energy.

Any energy absorbed by the Ideal Black Body would be radiated away. Since all the energy is radiated away, there is no energy remaining to raise the temperature of the Black Body.

Comment: So how to reason the blackbody curve, which is described for different temperatures?

Comment: @LDC3, Please reconsider your statement: *"Ideally, any energy absorbed by the Black Body would then be radiated away. Since all the energy is radiated away, there is no energy remaining to raise the temperature of the Black Body."*  A perfect blackbody fully absorbs all radiant energy striking it from its ambient environment (given its $\epsilon =1$ absorptivity). A blackbody at a lower temperature emits radiant energy equally efficiently, but at a lower rate, due to its lower temperature.  The difference between an ideal and real experiment is not being able to obtain a perfect blackbody.